# How to install dart on ec2 linux instance?

Tags: dart, amazon-ec2

Many dart installation tutorials use apt-get command, which is not available on ec2 aws. Only yum is available. So just wanted to know how do you install dart using yum.

Comment: You could also just download the zip file and unpack it: https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive . If you just want to run Dart applications, you don't even need the Dart SDK if you have compiled your program to an executable.

Answer (score 0):

EC2 instance can be created different type of OSs. If you want to create an EC2 instance with **apt-get**, try to create it from ubuntu **AMI** (i.e ubuntu 20.04). The one you have is based on Centos or Redhat, which are using **yum** as a package manager not **apt**.